# If there is an NHL lockout / partial lockout, what will happen to purchased tickets?

Tags: rules, nhl

I bought tickets for the Boston Bruins' opening night against the Montreal Canadians on October 18, 2012. What will happen to the tickets that people have bought if there is a lockout?

Also there is a possibility that there will be a partial lockout and the season will start in December rather than October (*like the NBA 2011-2012 season*). If this happens, and "opening night" gets moved from October 18th to December 1st, what will happen to all of those who bought tickets for games between those two dates?

Comment: This is a general question about tickets.

Comment: This [article](http://ducks.ocregister.com/2012/08/31/ducks-prep-ticket-holders-for-lockout/112838/) talks about how the Anaheim Ducks will refund their season ticket holders...it would lead me to believe that individual teams have different policies and procedures, but that's just a vague hypothesis.

Comment: I think these refund policies will be used league round. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just found this article that goes over what every team in the league is doing... http://daysofyorr.com/2012-articles/september/cashing-in-on-the-lockout-what-teams-are-offering-season-ticket-holders.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know for season tickets they told me that I don't pay for games that aren't played.  So I think they refund anything that you may have purchased once the schedule is decided. As for individual tickets I would bet it is the same as a canceled event.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, who are you a season ticket holder for?

Comment: The Colorado Avalanche.